# Is there a freelance website dedicated to high-end work, like writing compilers?

Tags: freelancing

I've read through the previous posts on freelance websites and used most of them. I'm looking for a website dedicated to high-end professionals and high-end work. Such as writing software compilers, designing database engines, etc.

Probably no such website exists (there would have to be some kind of moderation), but I'm really hoping there is one, both as an employer and as a developer.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, I don't think a such thing exists. This may (or may not) be due to the fact that most of these technologies are either a) open source and thus driven by the OS community (not freelancing), or b) are driven by large corporations who covet their IP and sharing it with a freelancer would be the last thing on earth in their minds (other than hiring a consultant for a contract, but that would be done directly through the company and not a freelance system).